# How to write conditional css?

Tags: html, css

If user hovers on **div1**, **div2** should get highlighted.
How to write such conditional css?
HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class='div1'></div>
  <div class='div2'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have  you tried? Please post your attempts.

Comment: you'll need javascript for this. Give it a try and post your code if you're having issues.

Comment: @Toby No need for JavaScript, can be done with CSS.

Comment: It can easily be done with just CSS. But you should at least try something first

Comment: Well, it depends what 'highlighted' means..

Comment: What definition of "highlighted" are you thinking of that couldn't be handled by CSS @Toby?

Comment: Alright, adjacent selector will do it for altering style.. my bad. For all this conversation someone could have just posted an answer.. lol.

Comment: Principles or something @Toby ;)

Comment: You do not really need js for this, but it's much better to do it with JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/jstam/2cdaV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used the sibling selector `~`.

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
}
.div2 {
  background: blue;
}
.div1:hover ~ .div2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
```

If there would be more than 1 `div2` and you only want the first immediate use the adjacent sibling selector `+`

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
}
.div2 {
  background: blue;
}
.div1:hover + .div2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton  @LGSon , that's wxact what I was looking for.